# Is it possible to add a spring interceptor in a spring security filter chain?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to retrieve the path param map in my spring boot application and I noticed that the following line of code:

```
final Map<String, String> pathVariables = (Map<String, String>) request
         .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

only works when in a spring boot InterceptorHandler class, I guess because the "path param" abstraction is spring's.

Problem is that I'm using spring security, defining my own filter chain:

```
http.addFilterBefore(...).addFilterAfter(myFilterNeedingPathParam) //series of filters
```

And the last filter needs the path params map. My idea would be to put the interceptor before or, if you want, make sure that the last filter is executed after.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

When in the Spring InterceptorHandler, check the actual class of the request, you may need to cast your request to that.  Also look into the source code for that class and see if it's pulling that value from a ThreadLocal of some sort.